# Faster/more efficient way of adding Markers/Polylines/Polygons to Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Currently right now I have a a database (Call is `database1`) of map elements (Marker Points,Polyline Points and Polygon points with their information) and for the polyline/polygon points I keep their points (Lat/Lng) in a separate database (call this `database2`) where each point is a separate database item referenced with the element id of `database1`.

When the MapFragment loads I pull everything from the database in an `AsyncTask`

```
c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MapElements.CONTENT_URI,new String[] { MapElements.ID,MapElements.LOCATION_STRING,MapElements.LAYER_ID,MapElements.NEW_OR_MOD}, null, null, null);
```

loop through the cursor and if the element is a polyline or polygon I pull all the points with the `id` of that element and create a List to later put into creating the line or polygon

```
Cursor c2 = context.getContentResolver().query(MapPoints.CONTENT_URI,new String[] { MapPoints.LAYER_ID, MapPoints.LATITUDE,MapPoints.LONGITUDE },
                        MapPoints.ELEMENT_ID + "=?",new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null);
    if (c2 != null && c2.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            locationArray.add(new LatLng(c2.getFloat(1), c2.getFloat(2)));
        } while (c2.moveToNext());

    }
c2.close();
```

Then I plot it to the map with the list

```
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(mElement.getLocationArray()));
```

This whole process can take a long time, for example using `250` different elements takes about 10-15 seconds to load them all and the number of map elements could be far-more or less so obviously the more points the longer it will take.

Looking at the google maps app it looks like all their markers load up real quick, Is there any way I can speed this up??

**UPDATE**

I did a a little digging around with what I could understand from the traceview and it says that `Handler` operations were the second and third longest running operations. So what I did was take out the handlers in my asynctask that I use to call back to the main thread to put to the map and the process completed in 2 seconds...

I pulled out the handler code and put it in its own method for now and this is the method

```
private void test(final MapElement mElement){
        if (mElement.getType() > 0) {
            try{
                Handler h = new Handler(getActivity().getMainLooper());
                if (mElement.getType() == 3) {
                    h.post(new Runnable(){

                        public void run() {
                            Polygon poly = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                            .addAll(mElement.getLocationArray()));

                    String color = mElement.getFillColor();
                    String borderColor = mElement.getBorderCOlor();

                    poly.setFillColor(Color.parseColor("#"+color));
                    poly.setStrokeColor(Color.parseColor("#"+borderColor));
                    poly.setStrokeWidth(4);

                    poly.setVisible(false);

                    Marker m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(mElement.getPoint())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(mElement.getMarkerIcon())));

                    m.setVisible(false);
                    m.setSnippet(String.valueOf(mElement.getID()));
                    mElement.setMarker(m);

                    mElement.setPolygon(poly);
                        }

                    });
                    mapElements.put(mElement.getID(), mElement);
                } else if (mElement.getType() == 2) {
                    h.post(new Runnable(){

                        public void run() {
                            Polyline line = map
                                    .addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(mElement.getLocationArray()));

                            String borderColor = mElement.getBorderCOlor();

                            if(borderColor == null){
                                line.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                            }else{
                                line.setColor(Color.parseColor("#"+borderColor));
                            }

                            line.setWidth(mElement.getThickness());
                            line.setVisible(false);

                            if(mElement.getLayerId() != 16){
                                Marker m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(mElement.getPoint())
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(mElement.getMarkerIcon())));

                            m.setVisible(false);
                            m.setSnippet(String.valueOf(mElement.getID()));

                            mElement.setMarker(m);
                            }

                            mElement.setPolyLine(line);

                        }

                    });
                    mapElements.put(mElement.getID(), mElement);
                } else {
                    h.post(new Runnable(){

                        public void run() {
                            Marker m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(mElement.getPoint()).icon(
                                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(mElement.getMarkerIcon())));

                                m.setVisible(false);
                                m.setSnippet(String.valueOf(mElement.getID()));
                                mElement.setMarker(m);
                        }

                    });
                    mapElements.put(mElement.getID(), mElement);
                }
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MapElements.PLOTTED, 1);
                getActivity().getContentResolver().update(Uri.withAppendedPath(MapElements.CONTENT_ID_URI_BASE,String.valueOf(mElement.getID())), values, null, null);


            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Even taking out the handlers and putting the `test` method in the onPostExecute still causes the delay. It take `0.058 seconds` to complete this method once so multiplying that by 250 comes out to `15 seconds`

So this seems the be the problem here, should I be handling this callback to the main thread differently?

Comment: Have you isolated the delay to the actual ploting and not the database calls?

Comment: When I say plotting I mean the whole process of getting/looping/putting to the map. The delay is probably more due to looping through everything then it is adding it to the map after I have all the values

Comment: What I am suggesting is to isolate delay. If you create 250 static items and attempt to loop through the listing and add them to the map is there a delay? If not your issue is the delay in pulling from the database and you should focus in that area to speed up the _entire_ proces.

Comment: When you used Traceview to determine exactly where you are spending your time, what did you learn?

Comment: @CommonsWare to be honest I am not sure what I am looking for in the traceview. I took a screenshot of it from fragment loading to everything loaded https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5qDXF5Bu-EnRnFLOU50U0VIaDA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't really tell you much from the screenshot, sorry.

Comment: I updated my question with more details of what I have found

Answer (score 0):

> loop through the cursor and if the element is a polyline or polygon I pull all the points with the id of that element

This is most probably your culprit. Every Hibernate user can tell you N+1 queries are very, very bad. Remove the loop, load all the points in one query and make the logic in code.

Comment: @tyczj This code is ineed a problem. Why not return `List<MapElement>` from `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute` and do a tight loop over them? Why do you need `ContentResolver.update`? Why do you even add all those objects to `GoogleMap` if you make them invisible?

Comment: there is more to how the map elements work then just plotting. think like the google maps app where you can enable and disable layers so I have different layers of map elements. I hide them all at first then show ones that should be enabled later on. I did do a test returning a `List<MapElement>` in the onPostExecute but it had no effect on the speed and even held up the UI at times. The update (which I forgot about) is there to tell me if a push comes in saying there is some new map element that needs to be plotted I just look for anything that is `0` meaning it has not been plotted